# In Slick, how to filter based on a custom column properties?

Tags: scala, slick

I have a custom column in my Slick as follow:

```
class PgACL(tag: Tag) extends Table[ACL](tag, Some(schemaName), "ACL") {

    def id = column[UUID]("ID", O.PrimaryKey)
    def resourceSpec = column[ResourceSpec]("RESOURCE_SPEC")

    def * = (id, resourceSpec) <>(ACL.tupled, ACL.unapply)
  }
```

and the custom class:

```
case class ResourceSpec (val resourceType: String, val resourceId: String)
```

And I map them like this:

```
implicit val ResourceSpecMapper = MappedColumnType.base[ResourceSpec, String](
    resourceSpec => resourceSpec.resourceSpecStr,
    str => ResourceSpec.fromString(str)
  )
```

I am trying to have a query which filter based on a property of the custom column, but I don't know how I can access to it. For example I want to have:

> TableQuery[PgACL].filter(x => x.resourceSpec.resourceType === "XYZ")

But x.resourceSpec returns Rep[ResourceSpec] and I don't know how to get its "resourceType" property.
Any help?

Comment: You can't, in your mapper you are telling to use `resourceSpecStr` as value in the column, that means that your `ResourceSpec` will be stored as a string and not as an object, you can only do `.filter(_.resourceSpec === "XYZ")`.

Comment: Right! I missed that. Thanks.